# PDO not inserting rows the way the tutorial said it would

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've never used PDO before, but decided finally that security is the primary concern and I have to switch from my familiar inbuilt mysql statements to something more secure. The db_connect() function in dbconn.php works just fine, pretty much copy and pasted from a PDO tutorial and tested with multiple SELECT statements successfully.

```
    include "dbconn.php";

    db_connect();

    //INSERT INTO  `a4331098_VAtest`.`VA_GPS` (`gID` , 'gtruck' , `gLat` , `gLong` , `gAlt` , `gTime`) VALUES (NULL , '434' , '47.558',  '-76.557',  '543',  '0111588448');
    $pTruck = $_POST['gTruck'];
    $pLat = $_POST['gLat'];
    $pLong = $_POST['gLong'];
    $pAlt = $_POST['gAlt'];
    $pTime = $_POST['gTime'];

    //echo $pTruck . "<br />" . $pLat . "<br />" . $pLong . "<br />" . $pAlt . "<br />" . $pTime . "<br /><br />";

    $stmt = $dbconn->prepare("INSERT INTO a4331098_VAtest.VA_GPS VALUES (NULL , ':fTruck' , ':fLat' , ':fLong' , ':fAlt' , ':fTime')");
    $stmt->execute(array(':fTruck' => $pTruck , ':fLat' => $pLat , ':fLong' => $pLong , ':fAlt' => $pAlt , ':fTime' => $pTime));
    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
    echo $affected_rows;
```

I know the correct values are being passed to the script (the commented out echo showed me that) but for some reason $affected_rows keeps returning 0. The structure of the DB is gID (being passed NULL, as it autoincrements), gTruck, gLat, gLong, gAlt, gTime. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Uncomment the echo and paste the result, is the data that you want to insert valid?

Comment: Add [`$stmt->errorInfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) after `execute()`. It will help you determine the SQL error, if any.

Comment: Do you get an error from PDO?  You can use `PDO::errorInfo` or turn on the exception error mode.

Comment: It's definitely the quotes like freejosh stated.

Comment: To debug this in the future, turn on query logging and you will be able to see the exact select statement generated by pdo.

Comment: Wow, you guys are quick. @KA_lin yes, the values were valid. Jason McCreary it was coming up with HY093, until I tried Weacked's suggestion which fixed it, and errorInfo() then returned 000.  aziz punjani how exactly do I turn on query logging? If I had done that I probably could have solved this myself, but I truly appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the quotes around the variables in your statement. PDO will insert them or not based on the type of value.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was definitely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use simple quotes with your PDO :variables. If you do, pdo will be looking for a column named `':variable'` and will not use the assigned value.

Try this :

```
 $stmt = $dbconn->prepare("INSERT INTO a4331098_VAtest.VA_GPS VALUES (NULL , :fTruck , :fLat , :fLong , :fAlt , :fTime)");
```

and tell us what happen with the `$stmt->errorInfo()`

Good luck

**EDIT**:

Don't forget that PDO's variable are, by default, inserted with quotes, so it'll prevent any risk of sql injection and protect your database.

That's why you don't need to insert quotes yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much, that code worked perfectly. The tutorial I was using had them in single quotes so I figured that was the right way, but now I understand. Thank you again